# Nodejs Graphql with data from Azure SQL

Tags: node.js, promise, graphql-js

I'm trying to write a graphql API. This fetches data from an Azure SQL and throws up only the data attributes which are requested. I can see that the SQL is read successfully for the correct record but only empty fields are displaying on the response.

I feel I'm going wrong somewhere with the promise which is returned from reading the SQL and would appreciate some help in fixing this.
My code looks like this :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql').graphqlHTTP
//app.use(express.json());

var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
const sql = require('mssql');

const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()

var { buildSchema } = require('graphql');

var schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
        course(id: Int!): Course
        courses(topic: String): [Course]
    },
    type Course {
        id: Int
        title: String
        author: String
        description: String
        topic: String
        url: String
    }
`);

var config = {
    server: "xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net",
    user: process.env.SQLUSERNAME,
    password: process.env.SQLPSWRD,
    database: "xxxxxx",
    options: {
        trustedconnection: true,
        enableArithAbort : true
    }
};

async function readsql(id) {
    console.log('Reading SQL with id :' + id);
    try {
        let pool = await sql.connect(config);
        let products = await pool.request().query("select * FROM [TestSchema].[Courses] WHERE [id] =" + id);
        //console.log(products.recordsets);
        return products.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

var getCourse = function(args) { 
    var id = args.id;
    console.log("Getting a course "  + args);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        readsql(id).then(result => {
            console.log("Inside : ");
            console.log(result[0]);
            return resolve(result[0].filter(course => {
            //return promiseData(result[0]).filter(course => {
                console.log(course.id);
                console.log(id);
                return course.id == id;            
            }));
        })
    })
}

let promiseData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getCourse((course) => {
            resolve(course);
        });
    });
};

// The root provides a resolver function for each API endpoint
var root = {
    course: getCourse,
};

app.use('/graphql', expressGraphQL({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true
}));

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

I send in the following query

```
query getSingleCourse($courseID: Int!) {
    course(id: $courseID) {
        title
        author
        description
        topic
        url
    }
}
```

with the following query variables :

```
{ 
    "courseID":1
}
```

And the response I get is

```
{
    "data": {
        "course": {
            "title": null,
            "author": null,
            "description": null,
            "topic": null,
            "url": null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what about the execution logs, I see you have some var printed, would be interesting to have the exec output to help you debug this. You also may want to set your getCourse function async, since you're returning a Promise

Comment: Thanks so I tried what you suggested and the response was still null. The console output for a query with id 2 was "Getting a course [object Object]
Reading SQL with id :2
Inside : 
[
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Node.js, Express & MongoDB Dev to Deployment',
    author: 'Brad Traversy',
    description: 'Learn by example building & deploying real-world Node.js applications from absolute scratch',
    topic: 'Node.js',
    url: 'https://codingthesmartway.com/courses/nodejs-express-mongodb/'
  }
]
2
2"